# NSUserDefaults setObject forKey causing exception in ios7

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, ios7, nsuserdefaults

I was trying to save a `NSString` to `NSUserDefaults`. Its working fine in `iOS6`,`iOS5` versions. But in `iOS7` its crashing with a message

> [NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert non-property
>   list object

```
NSUserDefaults *missedValues=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableDictionary *temp=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[temp setObject:name forKey:@"missedName"] ;
[missedValues setObject:temp forKey:@"missed"];
[missedValues synchronize];
```

An exception is thrown when setObject method is called. How can this be fixed ? The issue is only with `iOS7`.

Comment: @trojanfoe no name is not nil

Comment: You are setting NSMutableDictionary(temp) to "missed" key.

Comment: Will it crash if you use `NSDictionary *temp=@{@"missedName":temp};` ?

Comment: Use this ----> [missedValues setObject:[temp objectForKey:@"missedName"] forKey:@"missed"];

Comment: There are two lines with setObject:forKey: -> which one is crashing?

Comment: @Volker the second one where i am trying to set the NSUserdefaults is causing the crash

Comment: is name a property list element (e.g. NSString) or a custom object?

Comment: @Volker its an NSString